# Return string in Java does nothing in compiler

Tags: java, string, loops, return

My goal is to reverse a string from "def" to "fed."

In this example (below), the value of new_string is not returned. *Literally, the console appears blank.*

```
public class ReverseString {

public String reverse(String input) {
    String new_string = "";
    int iterator = 0;
    int length = input.length();

        while(iterator < length){
            char string_input = input.charAt(iterator);
            new_string = string_input + new_string;
            iterator ++;
        }
    return new_string;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    ReverseString test = new ReverseString();
    test.reverse("def");
}
}
```

However, when I change my code to do a system print, I get the correct result "fed."

```
public class ReverseString {

public void reverse(String input) {
    String new_string = "";
    int iterator = 0;
    int length = input.length();

        while(iterator < length){
            char string_input = input.charAt(iterator);
            new_string = string_input + new_string;
            iterator ++;
        }
    System.out.println(new_string);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    ReverseString test = new ReverseString();
    test.reverse("def");
}
}
```

The question is:
Why when return the result is blank?

Comment: Why do you think the value of `new_string` is not being returned?

Comment: Hint: If you do not have any print statements in your code, why are you surprised when nothing is printed?

Comment: thanks for your input azurefrog. I just assumed that the return new_string would print the value of the string to the console on its own. I had no idea that I needed to run the method inside of system.out.print in the main method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted something like this? Return a string variable. Print it out.

```
public class ReverseString {

public String reverse(String input) {
    String new_string = "";
    int iterator = 0;
    int length = input.length();

        while(iterator < length){
            char string_input = input.charAt(iterator);
            new_string = string_input + new_string;
            iterator ++;
        }
    return new_string;
}



public static void main(String[] args){
    ReverseString test = new ReverseString();
    System.out.println(test.reverse("def"));
}
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do!  I've actually never seen this done in Java before so I had no idea what was missing.

Comment: That being said, read the answer below mine, that's a better explanation than I mustered. :P

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

For any method which has return value, you have to return the particular value. But, you need not use it.
It is exactly what happened in your case 1. You performed an action, returned the value and didn't use it.

**Possible Solution**

If you would like to see the result printed on your console, modify the method calling line in main as following [In you first code].

```
System.out.println(test.reverse("def"));//used the return value.
```

---

**Understanding Method returns**

Syntax is as follows

```
<return_type> <name/ID>(<parameters>){
   //....code
   return <reference of return__type/an object of return_type>;//return_value statement
}
```

*returnvalue* statement is not written when *returntype* is *void*.

Whenever *returnvalue* is returned you have an option to use it or not.